# Nested NSNotification for NSTableViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have two table views controlling the display/sorting of a collection of objects (namely, by Category and Localization, i.e. Lieu).
My problem is : I want the selection to be updated when the user clicks on a cell inside any of those Table Views (which is working just fine using NSTableViewDelegate), but I also want to restore the selection to the default one in the other Table View.

My problem is then obvious : every call to tableViewSelectionDidChange triggers another call to himself, which makes the result quiet unstable. Is there a way to prevent this call `[tableViewCategory selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] byExtendingSelection:NO];` from triggering a notification ?

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{   

    if ([[[aNotification object]identifier]isEqualToString:@"table2"]){
        //First, reset AnnonceWithCategory
        [tableViewCategory selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] byExtendingSelection:NO];
        //Then
        [self showAnnoncesWithLieu];
    }
    else if ([[[aNotification object]identifier]isEqualToString:@"table3"]){
        //First, reset AnnonceWithLieu
        [tableViewLieu selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] byExtendingSelection:NO];
        [self showAnnoncesWithCategory];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent the `NSTableView` from sending the notification, but you can prevent your class from responding to it. You could do something like this:

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{   

    if ([[[aNotification object]identifier]isEqualToString:@"table2"] && ! _currentlyUpdatingTable2){
        //First, reset AnnonceWithCategory
        _currentlyUpdatingTable2 = YES;
        [tableViewCategory selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] byExtendingSelection:NO];
        _currentlyUpdatingTable2 = NO;
        //Then
        [self showAnnoncesWithLieu];
    }
    else if ([[[aNotification object]identifier]isEqualToString:@"table3"] && ! _currentlyUpdatingTable3){
        //First, reset AnnonceWithLieu
        _currentlyUpdatingTable3 = YES;
        [tableViewLieu selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] byExtendingSelection:NO];
        _currentlyUpdatingTable3 = NO;
        [self showAnnoncesWithCategory];
    }
}
```

...where `_currentlyUpdatingTable2` and `_currentlyUpdatingTable3` are ivars of the object receiving the notification.

Comment: Works like a charm; although you had a small logic error which I fixed in your answer (`! _currentlyUpdatingTable3`<-`! (_currentlyUpdatingTable3 || _currentlyUpdatingTable2)`. Thanks a lot